# Use Input::old on multiple select

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multiple-select

hello guys i have some problem here..

```
// in controller
$select = \MyTable::select('id','name')->where('myWhere',valWhere)->get();
return this->data['select'];

// in view
<input type="hidden" name="inselect" value="">
<select name="sel" multiple>
foreach($select as $val)
   <option value="{{ $val->id }}">{{ $val->name }}</option>
</select>
```

because im using multiple select plugin, input name="inselect" will containt selected id. so after selection "inselect" will be containt like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="inselect" value="2,4,5"> // string value
```

and i want return this "2,4,5" with Input::old('inselect'). how to get it?

Comment: `Input::old('inselect') ` should be = `2,4,5`. All you need to do is `<input type="hidden" name="inselect" value="{{ Input::old('inselect')  }}">`

Comment: also if you are using laravel 5 you can use `{{ old('inselect') }}` for previously posted values

Comment: i think you misunderstanding my question.. my question mean "2,4,5" this value convert to array and put in into select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="inselect" value="">
<select name="sel" multiple>
foreach($select as $val)
   <option value="{{ $val->id }}" @if (in_array($val->id, Input::old('sel'))) selected @endif >{{ $val->name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah this is what im looking for. thanks sir. nice job, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

or shorter:

```
{{in_array($val->id, old("sel") ?: []) ? "selected": ""}}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.